# xml parser problem in alexa using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, alexa-skills-kit

```
    var xml = require('XML-Parser-master');
        const fs = require('fs');
 var responseString = 'html string';

        var finalString="";


        var xmlDoc = new xml.DOM(xml.parse(responseString)); 

        const items =xmlDoc.document.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length ; i++) {
          const item = items[i];
          var name = (item.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]),
             status = (item.getElementsByTagName('status')[0]),
             device = (item.getElementsByTagName('device')[0]),
             probe = (item.getElementsByTagName('probe')[0]),
             message_raw = (item.getElementsByTagName('message_raw')[0]);

            finalString += "Il sensore "+name+ ", sul server "+device+ " del  "+probe+ " è nello stato"+status+". Il messaggio di errore è: "+ message_raw+". ";

        }

          });
           res.on('end', function(res)
            {
                const speechOutput = finalString;
                console.log("==> Answering: ",speechOutput); 
                mythis.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
            });
```

The proble is that it returns " [object Object] " when it should add a different string to  name,status,device,probe and message_raw.
Example:

> il sensore [object Object], sul server [object Object] del  [object Object] è nello stato[object Object]. Il messaggio di errore è: undefined."
>       }

parser used is : https://github.com/MauriceConrad/XML-Parser#readme

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the XML Parse module [XML Parse npm module docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-parse), it looks like you just need to set the variable to the `text` property of the object.

For example,

```
var name = (item.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]).text;
```

Comment: nope, it didn't work. But I had used  JSON.stringify(name);